# How to reference System.Threading.Tasks, MySql and MysqlConnection with Mono

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, mono

I am trying to run a C# console application on my server which is running Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have installed Mono JIT version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2) and additional packages like `gmcs` and `MonoDevelop`. The file that I am trying to execute is called `Program.cs` and when I run the command `$gmcs Program.cs` I get the following errors:

```
error CS0234: The type or namspace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace 'system.Threading'. Are you missing assembly reference?

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I have researched into referencing the .dll files for the above namespaces but have not been able to find an answer that is clear. Most forum links suggest that I install mono - trunk, but I want to know if I should uninstall the existing mono package and then install mono-trunk.

I am new to the Unix platform and researching every step of my way. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling from the command line, you will need to pass the referenced assemblies as a series of `/r` or `/pkg` switches, such as:

```
mcs /r:MySql.Data.dll Program.cs
```

Obviously you will need to have the required assemblies installed too.

Also note that `gmcs` is an (old) alias for the .net 2.0 compiler, that's why it doesn't see `System.Threading.Tasks` (which is a .net 4 feature). See the `-sdk` switch of `mcs`.

You should probably install monodevelop to have a user-friendly IDE to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I upgraded to Mono 3.0 and was able to reference System.Threading.Tasks using 'mcs Program.cs'. I have to now install mysql assemblies from the MySql website and then reference them.                                                               Regarding MonoDevelop: Can I use MonoDevelop IDE if am using Ubuntu server 12.04 as my OS. I have no GUI interface installed to optimize my server capabilities.